# generic ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

ajax/javascript problem:
I have an app which consist of multiple forms. What i want to achieve is to make a generic js function to submit forms to their respective controllers by getting form id.. I m successfully getting form ids in form_id variable but m unable to use them. I tried replacing $('patient_form') with form _id and got following error: TypeError: form_id.on is not a function

Here is the following code for better understanding of the problem:

```
$(function () {
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    var form_id = "'#" + form[0].id + "'";

    form_id.on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Controllers/c_insertPatient.php',
            data: $('#patient_form').serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you want to keep your form ID dynamic, right, so you can insert whatever values you want?

```
$(function () {
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    // note you have to convert to jQuery object
    var form_id = $("#" + form[i].id); // i, so you can put in the id for any form

    form_id.on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Controllers/c_insertPatient.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(), // again, keep generic so this applies to any form
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });

      });

});
```

Comment: no not the form id, the php application have multiple forms with their own respective ids and i just wanted to save typing redundant code for each and every form. Besides the above provided solution worked for me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it form_id is a string.

Try:
`var form_id = $("#" + form[0].id);`

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` is a jquery function. If you want to use jquery (which in this case I think you should), then do it as follows:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    $(this).preventDefaults();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'Controllers/c_insertPatient.php',
        data: $('#patient_form').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the event listener to the element, not the string of the id of the element. Also I presume you have jQuery because you are using `$`. Set an id on the form in the HTML. Then:

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#theFormId');

    form.submit(function(event) {

       $.post('Controllers/c_insertPatient.php', form.serialize(), function() {
           alert('success');
       });        


       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```